# CSS style to prevent scrolling along the y axis

Tags: css

Is there a way to position a column in a table so that it doesn't scroll along the x axis, but scrolls along the y? Perhaps some way to use absolute positioning that only effects one (like a spreadsheet. The header stays at the top, like absolute positioning)?

*Note: I want to avoid using Javascript*

*EDIT: I need to have the overflow for the table set to scroll*

OK I found an example that works the way I want: http://cross-browser.com/x/examples/xtable.php,
or this one: http://www.disconova.com/open_source/files/freezepanes.htm but I can't figure out what they do to make it work.

---

I ended up using Javascript anyway.

For fixed columns I found a great Javascript toolkit called DataTables and it has a plug-in called FixedColumns that allows fixed columns. [Link](http://www.datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/).

Comment: I'm not sure I get entirely what you mean, can't you have a container with no overflow though?

Comment: I need it in a container with overflow, with the first column not scrolling along with the rest of the content. Sort of like an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: but theres no way to only have one column in a table fixed and the others scroll, either you need seperate tables or use divs.  You can not do this with a single table though.

Comment: as for your edit, they use seperate divs and tables to produce that effect as I stated before.  If you right click and inspect the element you can see the structure they use.

Comment: what about this one:http://www.disconova.com/open_source/files/freezepanes.htm. I don't think this one uses separate tables.

Comment: yeah if you look closley at the code it does use several tables, one for the left row headers, one for the column headers and one for the data, although looking at their code is a tad confusing I must admit, mainly due to the sheer amount of data there is in it too.  They essentially do what I do in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with tables you would have to do something like this

```
<table>
    <tr><td>col1 name</td><td>col2 name</td></tr>
</table>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>col1 row1 data</td><td>col2 row1 data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col1 row2 data</td><td>col2 row2 data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col1 row3 data</td><td>col2 row3 data</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then you need to set styles appropriatley, make sure that the widths of each cell in the header is the same as the width you set for each column in the second table this will make your header and the data table lign up.  Make the div scrollable so the data parts of the table will scroll while the header parts remain static.

You could do a similair thing for row headings too by placing a table to the left of the data table and making sure you offset the column header table appropriatley to the right.

I am not going to write out all the css though as I am sure you can figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you use

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

For example, take a look at this website.

http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

In the following example we can create a table inside a table, not the cleanest idea but it should work.

```
<TABLE BORDER="2" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="5">
<TD>
<div style="width:325px; height:48px; overflow-y:scroll;">
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="3">
           <TD>inside the first one<br />
           we can add text and enable<br />
           overflow-y for vertical<br />
           scrolling.</TD>
</TABLE>
</div>
</TD>
<TD> This is a different table. You can edit this to fit your needs.</TD>
</TABLE>
```

**Note:** Head over to w3schools to try it on the fly, that way you can test it and learn from it ;) - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

Comment: Is there a way to do that with just one column?

Comment: Check out the website for a list of many examples; but yes, "overflow-y: hidden" will only hide vertical scroller.. if you were to use "overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;" then this will only enable the x-axis and the y-axis is hidden.

Comment: yes but this is not for a single column of a table this would only work for an entire table.

Comment: The table inside a table would only work by setting the second table in a td with colspan big enough to fill the entire width of the table, you would also need another td to handle the headers.

Comment: Good point Jon, and it is inside a TD Tag ;) it appears to work good. Tested it a sec ago.

Comment: yeah I noticed the td tag but you need to have the colspan and another td to handle the header.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the table in a container with a fixed width and set it's overflow property.

```
<div id="foo">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#foo {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Your table will obviously need to have the data displayed width-wise. Adding more rows won't cause it to scroll unless you specify a height to the container as well.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iyuxoj)

Comment: I'm pretty sure he just wants a single row or single column to scroll.

Comment: @JonTaylor yeah I saw the edit. Can't do it with just one table element. Gotta split up the first column from the rest.